# Sidebar Dropping WP Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Have a crazy issue with a woocommerce product page...the sidebar is dropping only on a single product page but no other woocommerce pages...

see here: http://brachelleart.com/shop/vate-lamp/

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: The OP's link points to a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Page doesn't not exist. Thats your problem.